# How to update a property in an Javascript Object with ko.mapping - Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mapping

Assume we have the following Object :

```
var gridViewModelJs = 
    {"GridViewModel":{"Rows":[{"RowNumber":"1","Id":"6","Name":"FullNameOfUser","NumberOfUsers":"12","RegistrationDate":"10/15/2013"}],"FoundItems":"4","CurrentPage":1,"TotalPages":1,"ItemsPerPage":50,"PagingLinks":""}, 
    "EntityModel":{"Id":0,"PermissionIds":null,"Name":null,"NumberOfUsers":0,"PersianRegistrationDate":null,"RegistrationDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Authorizations":null,"Users":null,"Contents":null}};
var KoEntityViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(gridViewModelJs);
ko.applyBindings(KoEntityViewModel);
```

Above code works, for updating the `KoEntityViewModel.` I used the following code :

```
// receivedData is data that returns from jQuery Ajax
// I'm dead sure `receivedData` is correct
var doneFunc = function (receivedData) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(receivedData, KoEntityViewModel.EntityModel);
    showDetailsBlock();
};
```

But nothing update in `KoEntityViewModel.EntityModel`.
Please guide me how I can update `KoEntityViewModel.EntityModel` in above sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update the mapping after applying bindings, use three parameters:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(receivedData, {}, KoEntityViewModel);
```

Comment: Could you please describe more? what is `data` variable ?

Comment: @Mohammad Sorry, I guess it would be `receivedData` in your case. The `{}` is for passing options. The documentation isn't great on this.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't understand well :-(, what should I write instead of `{}`, should I write `EntityModel`

Comment: Nothing, just leave it empty. It's a placeholder for the second parameter. The code I posted should work as it is.

Comment: I've done it, The write way is `ko.mapping.fromJS(receivedData, {}, KoEntityViewModel.EntityModel);`